# How to stop Mail from forwarding all emails from one Gmail to another

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I have 2 Gmail accounts. When I tried adding one of them to the Mail app, something really annoying happened. The other Gmail account keeps receiving forwarded emails from this account. All emails in this added account were being forwarded there and I did not know how to stop that. I checked the Forwarding and POP/IMAP settings in both Gmails but there's no forwarding configured. I disabled POP, too. I tried disconnecting the two Gmail accounts in Google's setting, but problem still not solved. I don't understand, by now this account should know nothing about the other, but when I add it to the Mail app, the crazy forwarding started again.

Just to be clear, I only added one of the two Gmails to the Mail app, so the Mail app should not know anything about the other account. Then the wrong must be in Google's side, but I disconnected them and checked every setting, still have no clue why they still are linked somehow. I did nothing strange before, just having this two Gmail accounts and trying to add one to the Mail app, so I guess it shouldn't be a rare problem. But there seemed to be no relevant solutions when I googled. Could someone help me with this? Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding both accounts.

Comment: @unknowndomain Yes I tried that many times at the beginning.

Comment: Have you checked filters on your gmail accounts settings?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Yes, I have checked the filters and there is none, I haven't set up any filters on both accounts.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and once I unchecked (in the email I was receiving the forwards into) that I could send from the other email as an alias the problem stopped and the forwarding ceased.